# Eclipse Spring MVC file upload issue

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

i have try to upload the file in Spring MVC,under webcontnet directory,when upload the file it goes default eclipse work-space directory,like

> eclipseworkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Webapp/images/Plastic_model.png

The below code i have tried,

```
         String uploadDir = "/images/";
         String realPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath(uploadDir);

         File transferFile = new File(realPath + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename()); 
         file.transferTo(transferFile);
```

i need upload file inside Webcontent directory, how i can resolve this problem

**Update1:**

```
String paramValue = request.getSession().getServletContext().getInitParameter("upload.image.path");         
         String realPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath(paramValue);          
         File transferFile = new File(realPath + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename()); 
         file.transferTo(transferFile);
```

in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>upload.image.path</param-name>
 <param-value>/home/robert/eclipse-workspace/Webapp/WebContent/images</param-value>
</context-param>
```

i got file not found error:

> INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Webapp] is completed
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/robert/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Webapp/home/robert/eclipse-workspace/Webapp/WebContent/images/Plastic_model.png (No such file or directory)

Thanks in advance

Comment: it would be better if you manage the file path in web.xm (since uploading file into project make it heavier and better of with remote location ) and just get upload file path.

Comment: how i can do that ??

Comment: setting context path and calling it in Java Class like ,                                   `<context-param>
  <param-name>upload.image.path</param-name>
  <param-value>/home/Desktop/images</param-value>
 </context-param>` , and call the param-name

Comment: how i can get that value in controller ??

Comment: like `String file= getServletContext().getInitParameter("upload.image.path");
`  , you can view more on here https://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-get-context-param-value-in-java/

Comment: when i do u asper your suggestion,i got error

Comment: and the error is ?

Comment: check my code in update1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163892/discussion-between-robert-and-parlad-neupane).

Comment: sir, me pointing above comment is about not saving the data in project , but rather in remote location , otherwise i just stately posted an answer. For saving the data in WebContext may be related to how you map on your deployment assembly